# Jsoup/Java - How to extract data that is not inside a tag

Tags: java, html, tags, jsoup

I have to parse a HTML like this

```
<span class="legenda">Cargo a que concorre:</span> Vereador<br />
<span class="legenda">Nome para urna:</span> Adeilza<br />
<span class="legenda">Número:</span> 40656<br />
<span class="legenda">Estado:</span> Amapá<br />
<span class="legenda">Município:</span> Vitória do Jari<br />
<span class="legenda">Partido:</span> Partido Socialista Brasileiro - PSB<br />
<span class="legenda">Coligação:</span> Vitória para todos (PSB / PV / PRTB)<br />
```

I am using jsoup to parse and follow the examples, but I did not know how to get the values after  in this case. e.g "Vereador" or "Adeilza".
There is a way to do that with jsoup?

here is the link, if anyone wants to see all the html page.
view-source:http://www.eleicoes2012.info/adeilza-psb-40656/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `nextSibling` on a jSoup `Element` will give you the next `Node` it finds. In this case you can use the a selector for `span` elements with a class `legenda` and then call `nextSibling`. Quick example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.eleicoes2012.info/adeilza-psb-40656/").get();
Elements spans = doc.select("span.legenda");

for(Element span: spans) {
    System.out.println(span.nextSibling());
}
```

Produced this output for me:

> ```
> Adeilza Ribeiro de Souza
> 30 anos (09/08/1983)
> Almeirim/PA
> Solteiro(A)
> Dona de Casa
> Ensino Fundamental Incompleto
>
>  0 Votos
>  Vereador
>  Adeilza
>  40656
>  Amap&aacute;
>  Vit&oacute;ria do Jari
>  Partido Socialista Brasileiro - PSB
>  Vit&oacute;ria para todos (PSB / PV / PRTB)
> ```